# FQL stream table very inconsistent

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

FQL stream table is definitely inconsistent. In stream table doc, one can read `Each query of the stream table is limited to the previous 30 days or 50 posts, whichever is greater.`

I tried this simple query `SELECT created_time FROM stream WHERE source_id = A_FRIEND_ID` which return me only 5 results (the last one is from Sep 4). Then, adding a simple `LIMIT 20` to that query, like this `SELECT created_time FROM stream WHERE source_id = A_FRIEND_ID LIMIT 20` return me instead 13 results (last one from Aug 27, still in the 30 days range).

Following the 50 results or the last 30 days worth of data, I should have been able to retrieve more than 5 posts in the first query, right? And why adding the LIMIT 20 would return me more results then? That make no sense!

Oh and, playing with the created_time field in the WHERE clause did not help either. I tried to retrieve exactly 30 days worth of data for that same friend using created_time field like this `SELECT created_time FROM stream WHERE source_id = 100004130401362 AND created_time < 1347840000 AND created_time > 1345248000` which return me same thing as above, only 5 results.

Is there something obvious I'm missing here?